# What's the most effective way to implement a radar plot with 50 points at arbitrary locations using chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, radar-chart

Consider a sequence of data along the following lines:

```
data = [{angle:1.2,value:1.2},...,{angle:355.2: value:5.6}];
```

I'd like to display this data on a radially scaled plot (i.e. circular bands indicating how high the value of each point is) to show angle vs value. Angles will change by a small but uncontrollable quantity for each data set but there will always be ~50 of them spaced fairly evenly around the chart.

It looks like `chart.js` has two options which don't quite fit the bill:

- A Radar plot which appears to require a label per point but without an obvious way to control where those labels are applied.
- An x-y scatter which I could calculate x/y co-ordinates for but which doesn't have the radial scale to help visualise the value of each point.

Is there a way to combine the two perhaps or some option I've missed to control them to achieve the result I'm looking for here?

*Edit - for example, this shows the data but lacks a radial scale:*

https://jsfiddle.net/7d7ghaxx/4/

**Edit2 - This is the sort of thing I Would expect to see as a result:

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example image of what kind of chart you expect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Demo & Code :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jp4xm4?file=index.js

### Explanation:

1. Used a [scatter](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html) chart to plot points
2. Added (wrote) a chartjs [plugin](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html) that converts points from polar to cartesian on `beforeUpdate` so you don't have to worry about converting before every update
3. Made x & y grid (not axes through origin) hide by adding [`gridLines`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration)`: { color: 'transparent' }` and [`ticks`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration)`: { display: false }`
4. Made `min` and `max` (options in `ticks`) of both axes equal so that the orgin is at the center
5. Added a [`radialLinear`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html) scale for the polar grid

(Update 1)

6. Added a [tooltip label callback](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback) to show tooltip as (r,θ) instead of default (x,y)

(Update 2)

7. Added (wrote) a `beforeDraw` [plugin](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html) to fill the `ctx` with light blue color as the OP wanted

PS: (Pointing out just to be a little competitive) I have used chartjs (unlike other answers) because the OP wants a chartjs solution as it's clearly written in the question: "using chart.js". There might be solutions better than chartjs but that's irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Can you please help me in these below questions? I have taken reference of your example.

1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53011177/charts-js-plot-values-ticks-on-x-axis

2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53006335/charts-js-show-labels-outside-gridlines

3) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52994989/chart-js-polar-scatter-plot-values-on-chart-and-x-axis

Answer (score 6):

You can use D3 js Charts is usefull for radar chart check the example link bellow :

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
        //////////////////////// Set-Up ////////////////////////////// 
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

        var margin = {top: 100, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100},
            width = Math.min(700, window.innerWidth - 10) - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = Math.min(width, window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom - 20);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
        ////////////////////////// Data ////////////////////////////// 
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

        var data = [
                  [//Yourchart values
                    {axis:"",value:0.052},
                    {axis:"",value:0.052},
                    {axis:"",value:0.012},
                    {axis:"",value:0.012},
                    {axis:"",value:0.022},
                    {axis:"",value:0.052},
                    {axis:"",value:0.052},
                    {axis:"",value:0.021}           
                  ]
                ];
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
        //////////////////// Draw the Chart ////////////////////////// 
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

        var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(["#6cbb69","#CC333F","#00A0B0"]);

        var radarChartOptions = {
          w: 500,
          h: 300,

          maxValue: 0.15,
          levels: 5,
          roundStrokes: true,
          color: color
        };
        //Call function to draw the Radar chart
        RadarChart(".radarChart", data, radarChartOptions);
```

https://codepen.io/Nighamza/pen/bKmjGE