# Charts.js - Show labels outside gridlines

Tags: angular, d3.js, charts, chart.js, scatter-plot

I have created chart using chart.js library and whenever I am adding 
labels. Show labels outside gridlines

Here is my example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/scatter-polar-chart?file=index.js

Without Labels 
[image]

With Labels
[image]

Edit - 1
if you add labels, left side value 6 is not in the alignment with grid circle[image]

Comment: I don't understand the issue

Comment: @KunalKhivensara I have updated question.

Comment: @rishabh Issue is padding, not a Plotting when you add Labels then padding increase on circle

Comment: @IftekharDani - that's true. so, labels are visible under those axis instead of surrounding of the chart.